# Error: Could not find or load main class cgl.imr.worker.TwisterDaemon (In Ubuntu)

Tags: java, mapreduce, cloud

I'm using ubuntu 16.0 & jdk 1.8 to configure twister0.9 for single machine  followed all the steps in user guide  but when i run the command $TWISTER_HOME/bin/start_twister.sh follogin error is shown   Error: Could not find or load main class cgl.imr.worker.TwisterDaemon  please help me out.Thanks in advance... :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the $TWISTER_HOME is set by running cd $TWISTER_HOME command
2. Go one by one ie. first go into cd $TWISTER_HOME, then cd bin , then
   start the twister, because you can be sure that you are right
       in that folder

I think this may  help you , I will tell you if got some points on it further

Comment: Yes, I done it. But still it is not working... Giving me same error

Comment: did you find the answer @KiranRohra.. can you please help me.

Comment: @AchillesRamNakirekanti, Sorry not found